# How to add data to Many-To-Many field in Django DRF

Tags: python, django, api, dry

I'm new to Django DRF, trying to have a sports school project done. I have a model for coaches, classes and students. Here is a stripped version to keep it simple and easy:

```
class Student (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

 class Coach (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

 class ClassDetails (models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    class_coach = models.ForeignKey(Coach, related_name='coach_classes')
    class_members = models.ManyToMany(Student, related_name='student_classes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name
```

In order to list/add students to the class, I'm using the following serializer:

```
class ClassDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ClassDetails
    fields = ['id','class_name', 'class_coach', 'class_members]
    read_only_fields = ('id', 'class_name', 'class_coach')
```

Getting the data is working ok. Also, adding a coach is working fine, what is really giving me a hard time is adding a class member. I'm using the following view:

```
def member_add(self, request):
    my_class = ClassDetails.objects.get(pk = request.data['id']
    serializer = ClassDetailsSerializer(my_class, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response('Member added', status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```

I'm sending a POST body like:

```
{
    "id": 2, <- class id
    "class_members": [20] <- student's id to add to the class members
}
```

The problem is no matter how many students in the class, the above will remove them all and put student id 20 instead.

- How can I keep the current students and only ADD the new id to them?
- How can I as well remove a student's id without deleting the whole data in class_members field?

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using: class ClassDetailsView(ViewSet):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to define your model in a different way, here is an example -

First define your Class Detail like -

```
 class ClassDetails (models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name
```

then define your Student such as -

```
class Student (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    classDetail = models.ForeignKey(ClassDetails)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

and finally your coach as  -

```
class Coach (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    classDetail = models.ForeignKey(ClassDetails)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

this way you can use the nested feature - now your student is always linked to a class and also your coach is linked to your class.

Now you can say each class can have multiple students and also each class can have multiple coach. Now if Coach is unique per class you can write Coach Modals as -

```
class Coach (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    classDetail = models.OneToOneField(ClassDetails)
```

Editing My answer based on inputs --

to add a new id in manytomany type field
first you will have to create a student for eg.

```
s = Student.objects.create()
```

and then do something like

```
my_class = ClassDetails.objects.get(pk = request.data['id'])
```

to get the correct instance of classdetail and then do something like -

```
my_class.class_members.add(s)
```

to add a new student to your manytomany field in ClassDetails

You can customize it according to your needs, hoping this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Ranu, but the student can play multiple sports, for example, Karate & swimming, accordingly I'll need M2M not M2O which FK provides. Also, the coach can do multiple sports like for example Karate & street fight classes. My true issue is how to add an id in the M2M field while I keep its previous data?

Comment: Ok, I just replied according to your question. Was unaware of the other requirements.

Comment: do check if my updated answer helps you. May not be the exact answer though :)

Comment: Thanks Ranu, looks promising, just before I try this out, should I serialize my_class and do a serializer.save()? i.e. how can I save the my_class after the .add(s)?

Comment: if you have the correct instance of ClassDetails. you simply have to do a add. a new student will be added to mamytomany field and here you don't need to do a .save. it is like how .push work in js array. maybe ?

Comment: Thanks Ranu, worked like a charm... Any ideas on how to remove a student from the class_members? Is there a .remove like the .add?

Comment: may be deleting the student will remove from here also.  and I'm not aware of .remove or how to remove so let me know also if you find a way.

Comment: Thanks bro, I've upvoted & accepted your solution.

Comment: .remove works! :)

Comment: well thanks, Will try it sometime  :)