# DRF: trying to append and delete users in a many to many field model

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

hi I'm new to django rest framework where I'm creating a update and delete request in which a list of users will be passed in request and then either the one specified in the request will be appended to the existing or will be deleted from the existing users list

my files looks like this:

models.py

```
class team(models.Model):
    teamname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    creationtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(user, related_name='admin', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="id")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(user,help_text='Select members for this team')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.teamname
    
    def display_members(self):
        return ', '.join(members.name for members in self.members.all()[:])

    display_members.short_description = 'Users'
```

serializer.py

```
class TeamUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = team
        fields = ['id', 'members']
```

`views.py`

It looks like this:

```
"""
   :param request: A json string with the team details
   {
      "id" : "<team_id>",
      "users" : ["user_id 1", "user_id2"]
   }

   :return:

   Constraint:
   * Cap the max users that can be added to 50
   """
```

the code for views.py is like this of what i attempted:

```
def patch(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
    id = pk
    if 'members' in request.data.keys():
      new_members = request.data.get('members')
      existing_members = team.objects.get('id').values_list('members', flat=True)
      print(new_members)
      print(existing_members)
      all_memebers = new_members + existing_members
      request.data.update({'members': set(all_memebers)})
      serializer = TeamUserSerializer(usser, data=request.data, partial=True)
      if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save()
          return Response({"MSG":"Team Updated Successfully"})
      return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

)
```

**edit:**

url would be like this: `http://localhost:8000/teams/{id}/`id culd be like- 1,2,3 or so on...

then in data what i would be passing as json  would be like this:

```
{
  "members":[1,2,3,4]
}
```

supposedly the model field already has values like under members column would be like

`"members": [9,8,11,41,5]` in this case of append: it should become in db like-> `"members":[1,2,3,4,9,8,11,41,5]`

and in case of delete the one that are passed as json shall be removed from array of existing users in db

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead? Please [edit] your post to include more details about what you need help with. See [ask] for guidelines.

Comment: I have made the edits

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I just have a few questions to clarify. When you say "then in data what i would be passing as json would be like this:..." What kind of request is this? `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc.? And what do you need help with? What is your question?

Comment: it's a `PUT` and also for `DELETE`  request as we're appending and poping more users in the members field of a specific `{id}`

Comment: And what do you need help with?

Comment: I want to append more users and pop users from my members model field which is a list of users that are in a specific team

Comment: And what happens when you do a `PUT` to this endpoint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243588/discussion-between-sparsh-saxena-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: It should merge the list passed in json object to the one in the database and replace the merged one the database

Comment: yes, I understand what it *should* do, but what does it **actually** do?

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you mean by what does it actually do

Comment: What happens when you do the PUT request? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, what is the result?

Answer (score 1):

ManyToManyField need different approach to add and remove new objects.

for ex -

```
def patch(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
    id = pk
    if 'members' in request.data.keys():
      new_members = request.data.get('members')
      existing_members = team.objects.get('id').values_list('members', flat=True)
      print(new_members)
      print(existing_members)
      if serializer.is_valid():
          objectCreated = serializer.save()
          for memberToBeAdded in new_members:
              objectCreated.members.add(memberToBeAdded)
          return Response({"MSG":"Team Updated Successfully"})
      return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

Check the **add method** here.
You can also use the **remove function** of ManyToManyField when you want to remove an object.

[Check this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880765/how-to-add-data-to-many-to-many-field-in-django-drf/70880942#70880942)

You can always modify this to use in your case.